# Completable future to hit multiple rest service and combine result

Tags: java, multithreading, rest

I have a question:

I have rest enpoint which gives me 1000 result .per page every time  i have to increase the page
and make a new rest call with increased page number;
pagenum value will be 0,1,2, till total page.
I made an async call using a completable future by passing the pagenum.

So suppose total page is 5 so 5 thread will go and get the result
then I have to get the result and combine all the result.

for that i am using --respon = resp.get();
but i read its blocking call..

so My question is how to get results asynchronously and combine it.
in the below code I am doing future .get() will it stop to run the code asynchronously.

Please comment !!!!!!!!

```
for (int pagenum = 1; pagenum <=totalPage; pagenum++) {
            
        String respon=   CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                return new RestTemplate().exchange(getUsersByID(roleId, maxCount, 
                        pagenum), HttpMethod.GET,
                        entity, String.class).getBody();
            });             
                                try {
                                    respon = resp.get();
                                    
                                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                
            }
           
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of options could be to create combined future:

```
    int MAX_PAGE_NUM = 100;
    List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int pagenum = 1; pagenum < MAX_PAGE_NUM; pagenum++) {
        futures.add(  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return new RestTemplate().exchange(getUsersByID(roleId, maxCount,
                pagenum), HttpMethod.GET,
                entity, String.class).getBody();
        }), executor);
    }

    CompletableFuture combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[MAX_PAGE_NUM]));
    try {
        combinedFuture.get();
        
        for (CompletableFuture<String> future : futures) {
            String response = future.get();
            //process the response
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The example above should help you to run all pages request in parallel and process results once all futures are processed.

If you want to process every result concurrently, regardless of the rest, so that the response processing would be async, you could use thenApply() method.

```
    int MAX_PAGE_NUM = 100;
    List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int pagenum = 1; pagenum < MAX_PAGE_NUM; pagenum++) {
        futures.add(  CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            return new RestTemplate().exchange(getUsersByID(roleId, maxCount,
                pagenum), HttpMethod.GET,
                entity, String.class).getBody();
        }).thenApply( (s) -> {
            //process the response concurrently
            return s;
        }), executor);
    }

    CompletableFuture combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[MAX_PAGE_NUM]));

    try {
        combinedFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I would also recommend using timeout restriction on combinedFututre.get()

```
combinedFuture.get(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This article should help you with more details https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture